# SASL authentication with Zend_Cache_Backend_Memcached

Tags: php, zend-framework, appfog

Is the Zend_Cache capable of using SASL auth to connect to the memcachier server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using ZF 1.x, [the manual says](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.cache.backends.html) that Zend_Cache_Backend_Memcached uses the [memcache extension](http://php.net/book.memcache), which does not expressly support [memcached 1.4.3+'s SASL support](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/SASLHowto).

Indeed, if any PHP memcached library were to ever gain support, it would be [memcache**d**](http://php.net/book.memcached), not memcache.  [Yes, they are different things](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2659060/168868).  The reason for this is the old non-D'd extension uses an older version of the client library than the newer, D'd extension, which uses the new, official library.