# memcached new auto-negotiating client connection

Tags: php, ubuntu, memcached

I'm trying to use memcached store PHP session information, but PHP keeps telling me it can't connect:

> Warning: session_start(): open(memcached:11211/sess_hitr4obt9ofmmsvk9kfl8euqt6, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2)

Next, I tried telnetting into memcached from the server it's running on by doing: `memcached -l 127.0.0.1 -p 12345 -vv`

After that, I connected using: `telnet localhost 12345`

However, that just causes telnet to hang on

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Meanwhile, the server output just sits at: `<28 new auto-negotiating client connection`

I've left it running for quite some time, and so far nothing has ever happened (no timeout, no connection).

Am I missing something here?

Comment: The very first error suggests that PHP thinks it should be using a *directory* named "memcached:11211" to store session *files*.  Have you properly installed the [*correct* memcached extension](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2659060/168868) and [modified your INI settings](http://php.net/memcached.sessions)?

Comment: Here are the corresponding lines from my php.ini file.
session.save_handler = memcached
session.save_path = "memcached:11211"
Where memcached is defined in /etc/hosts to point to the IP address of the server I have memcached installed on.
Also, both the web server and memcache server are using memcached, not memcache, so I don't think that should be an issue.

Comment: Okay, apparently the CMS I was using was re-setting the session handler to files, so that's what caused the PHP error. What I still don't understand is why telnet doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

That's the result of a successful connection. Try `stats`; if telnet successfully connected you should get a result from memcached.