# Php Class 'Memcache' not found

Tags: php, memcached

I have project with plain php and in some part have `$memcache = new Memcache;` I debug and when beginning this line have fatal error - app die I check in my php info I have

```
memcached

memcached    support    enabled
             Version    2.2.0
libmemcached version    1.0.18
```

I check

```
ivan@ivan-PC:/usr/local/bin$ ps aux | grep memcached
ivan      2857  0.0  0.0  22804   960 pts/27   S+   13:44   0:00 grep --color=auto memcached
memcache 24913  0.0  0.0 325536  2160 ?        Ssl  11:55   0:00 /usr/bin/memcached -m 64 -p 11211 -u memcache -l 127.0.0.1
```

in log

```
Class 'Memcache' not found
```

in console I run memcache, but still app die. what need to do check ?

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit confused. "app dies", what app? Does PHP crash? Do you get any error logs? Is the only thing that causes the crashing is when you add that single line?

Comment: Class 'Memcache' not found

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Is the PHP extension for memcache installed and loaded? Just having memcache system daemon doesn't give the ability to use `new Memcache;`. There are a lot of questions regarding that error message, do you get any resolution when searching on them? eg https://stackoverflow.com/q/2659035

Comment: I solved this problem when `sudo pecl install pecl_http-2.5.5` because need php version 5.6 and then in php info I find memcache and memcached

Answer (score 2):

[Memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php) and [Memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php) are two different libraries.

Your php info says you have installed `memcached`.
Error says you are using `memcache`.

Try installing `memcache` and you should be fine.