# Class Memcached not found, PHP CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp, memcached, codeigniter-3

I started memcached service using task scheduler

```
schtasks /create /sc onstart /tn memcached /tr "'c:\memcached\memcached.exe' -m 512"
```

and also using

```
c:\memcached\memcached.exe -d install
c:\memcached\memcached.exe -d install
```

Also I included the `php_memcache.dll` into `/xampp/php/ext` folder and added the corresponding lines into `php.ini`.

```
extension=php_memcache.dll
[Memcache]
memcache.allow_failover = 1
memcache.max_failover_attempts=20
memcache.chunk_size =8192
memcache.default_port = 11211
```

I tried different versions of memcache and still I am encountering the same issue of "Class Memcached not found in ...". I'm using windows 10.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2659060/2568469)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP memcached Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659035/php-memcached-fatal-error-class-memcache-not-found)

Comment: Yep, but those are the answers for linux versions, but here in windows I need to change the php.ini file manually and there is no memcached.dll, just the memcache.dll. Do you suggest me to change the [memcache] in php.ini to [memcached].
PS: Installed memcached.exe but included memcache.dll[since there is no memcached.dll].

Answer (score 0):

`Memcached` and `Memcache` are two different extensions.

Your php.ini is referencing `Memcache` whilst you have installed `Memcached`.

This is a fairly common mistake in my opinion. Use `Memcached` as i think `Memcache` is deprecated.