# Class 'Memcache' not found in config.php file

Tags: php, macos, memcached, php-5.6, libmemcached

I am trying to run php with memcache support but I am constantly receiving this error message in the config.php file.

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Class 'Memcache' not found in <b>
```

Below is the relevant config.php snippet

```
require 'lib/Minify/Cache/Memcache.php';
$memcache = new Memcache;
if(@$memcache->connect('127.0.0.1', 11211)) {
    $min_cachePath = new Minify_Cache_Memcache($memcache);
}
```

The second line in above snippet is causing the issue.
I have installed php56 using brew.
I have installed php56-memcache using brew
I have also installed php56-memcached using brew

when I run `php -i | grep memcache` I can see both memcache and memcached enabled.

**here is the output**
[image: php -i | grep memcache]

Please help me out.
As mentioned in comments this is not a duplicate to [PHP memcached Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659035/php-memcached-fatal-error-class-memcache-not-found) as I have both modules installed and still I am not able to use.

Comment: @thamilan and also to_rest_all_who_marked_duplicate, do you guys even had a look at my question?
I clearly said I have both modules loaded, Go take a look at the accepted answer of the same question that you guys have tagged here, the 5th comment clearly states loading both modules shouldn't be a problem.
My Problem is different, so if you guys can't help, just leave the question untouched

Comment: solved it, thanks for help

Comment: hello @noobmaster69, how did you solve it? I have the same problem now)

Comment: Hey @GagBaghdasaryan, I do not remember very clearly, but I guess it was because I had two separate php installed (one mac's default and other I installed later). Make sure that the memcache and memcached that your are using is for the same version of php on which your website runs.

Comment: Hey @noobmaster69. Thanks, actually I already fixed the problem on my end. But I don't remember how :D