# Laravel 5 Error : Class 'App\Utils\Memcached' not found

Tags: php, laravel, memcached

I installed Memcached on centos 7 and according to phpinfo() Memcached 3.0.4 is available. I also checked for Memcached with ps -eaf | grep Memcached and it was ok.
But when I try to make an instance of Memcached() in laravel it returns an Error :

```
"Class 'App\Utils\Memcached' not found"
```

This is my code :

```
<?php

namespace App\Utils;

class MemTools {

    private $mem;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->mem = new Memcached();
        $this->mem->addServer('localhost',11211) or die ("Could not connect");
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2659060/1227923

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP memcached Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659035/php-memcached-fatal-error-class-memcache-not-found)

Comment: No it is not a duplicate question. I know memcached and memcache are different. I installed memcached and used memcached.

Comment: is there any file physically named Memcached?? you could share that file too as it could help others to understand your problem better

Comment: @Sohel0415 No i have no any file or class named Memcached. I have only MemTools class.

Comment: @Sohel0415 but when i make an instance of MemTools in another class, Laravel returns that error.

Comment: `No i have no any file or class named Memcached.` so what do you expect to create an instance of? You can't just create instances of php extensions out of thin air...

Comment: @btl Thanks but what should i do? I used a tutorial for memcached and there was no any class named Memcached.

Comment: Set your `config/cache.php` accordingly and use the `Cache` facade or `cache` helper. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/cache#configuration

Comment: @btl you said :  so what do you expect to create an instance of? but according to  http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.set.php it uses memcached class

Comment: I'd start with this: http://php.net/manual/en/class.memcached.php

Comment: The memcached class needs to be referenced from the global namespace, so you prefix it with a backslash: `$memcache = new \Memcache;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `Memcached` class in the `App\Utils` namespace by default.

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but normally you would:

- install the [Memcached PECL package](https://pecl.php.net/package/memcached),
- configure all your Memcached servers in `config/cache.php`,
- and then [use Laravel's cache API](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/cache#cache-usage).

All of this is detailed in the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/cache#configuration).

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to use memcached as a cach for database. I use memcached for data that needs to be read and written fast (in an online game).

Comment: You can use it for anything you want. Why do you think this is only for database cache?

Comment: If i didn't use laravel and just flat php what should i do to use memcached?

Comment: Using plain PHP I think you would use the PECL package directly.