# Troubling Running PHP 5.6 application locally on mac

Tags: php, macos, memcached

First off, I apologize for the lack of details. Due to the nature of my issue I'm not sure what details are needed to solve the problem.

A few details:

I'm running the newest version of mac osx and I'm running php5.6 (needed for this code base)

I'm getting the following error from my php application:

`Fatal error: Class 'Memcached' not found in`

I've scoured the web for a solution, but no luck yet. Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated. If you need any other details, please let me know and I'll be happy to provide them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP memcached Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659035/php-memcached-fatal-error-class-memcache-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Homebrew?

```
$ brew install memcached php56-memcached
```

And then in your `/etc/php.ini` you should append `extension=memcached.so`.

If that doesn't work, try

```
$ brew remove php56-memcached
$ brew reinstall php56 --enable-maintainer-zts --build-from-source php56-memcached
```

Comment: When running `brew install memcached php56-memcached` i get the following error:
`Error: No available formula with the name "php56-memcached"`