# "PHP Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found" occurred in object-cache.php of wordpress even after installed memcache extension

Tags: php, wordpress, memcached, amazon-elasticache

I tried to enable object cache for wordpress by using Memcache. And I put `object-cache.php` into /wp-content/, which I get from [Memcached Object Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/memcached/) plugin.

And then `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Memcache' not found` occurred. So I install memcache extension by executing `sudo yum -y install php-pecl-memcache` and `sudo service httpd restart`. But nothing changed.

I also tried to install `php-pecl-memcached`, not `php-pecl-memcache`. But nothing had changed.

I confirmed that `/etc/php.d/memcache.ini` file existed and `extension=memcache.so` is loaded in the file.

Please give me an advice to solve this.

When I tried that for new EC2 instance, it worked well. So I guess my environment is preventing in some ways. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

fire the command 
dpkg -l | grep php5
and check the packages installed. Check for php5-memcache and php5-memcached.

If not installed then install those

Comment: I installed php5-memcache and php5-memcached. And then restart Apache. But it still did not work.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171313/memcache-not-found-in-command-line-php-script

Comment: ``$ php -m | grep memcache`` and I can get 
``memcache``
``memcached``.

memcache should be installed already. But wordpress output error log ``PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Memcache' not found``